# How to use webpack to compile a single file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm setting up a typescript project which migrating from javascript files. The below is structure folder

```
src
--featureA
----script1.ts
----script2.ts
----index.ts
--featureB
----script1.ts
----index.ts
tsconfig.ts
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

My tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My webpack config

```
const { CheckerPlugin } = require("awesome-typescript-loader");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },

  devtool: "source-map",

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loaders: ["awesome-typescript-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CheckerPlugin()
  ],

  devServer: {
    before(app) {
    },
    contentBase: "web"
  }
};
```

My package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "typewiz": "^1.2.3",
    "typewiz-webpack": "^1.2.3",
    "webpack": "^4.20.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

Feature A and B are standalone and I dont have a main.js file served as an entry point. If I compile and minify feature A, I will get featureA.js file and deploy. That's a result I want to achieve.

I still don't know if this setup is ok for my requirement? and how can I use webpack to compile each feature on demand and the desired command look like this:

```
Input: npm compile featureA
Output: featureA.js (with minified)
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use multiple entry points? Like so:

```
  entry: {
    featureA: './src/featureA/index.ts',
    featureB: './src/featureB/index.ts'
  }
```

Webpack will compile both files into 2 separate bundles.

Comment: where should we put this `entry`? Can you explain more?